# Disable automatic formatting inside WordPress shortcodes

Tags: wordpress

I've seen the tutorials on creating a (raw) shortcode that leaves the code inside it untouched,

*http://www.wprecipes.com/disable-wordpress-automatic-formatting-on-posts-using-a-shortcode*

but unfortunately this only applies to one shortcode at a time... *and* because the `else` statement bypasses the normal filters and calls the functions directions. My other modifications to autop and texturize functions get ignored.

Is there a way to 1. match multiple shortcodes and 2. preserve my other add/remove filters to the_content?

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic page, home for `https://wphacks.com/`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

After implementing @helgatheviking's solution on multiple websites, I'm convinced that only these lines are required:

```
// Move wpautop filter to AFTER shortcode is processed
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop', 99);
add_filter('the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100);
```

Put them in your `functions.php` file and you're set.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that.  I've accepted this answer so that people will stop using my full code.

Comment: Where is shortcode_unautop defined? Is it a part of Wordpress?

Comment: @LarryK it's in [wp-includes/formatting.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.3/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L287)

Comment: Seriously, why is this not the default? I was getting all sorts of weird mangled output from a shortcode that was run through wpautop twice— dropped this in and it's perfect.

Comment: @NateBeaty Just yet another weird quirk of WordPress I suppose. wpautop() is one of those functions that seem quite dated just in general, but these behaviours make it more than a little annoying.

Comment: Anybody remember in what part of functions.php?

Comment: @user1422434 it would depend on your theme, because there's no standard structure for functions.php

Comment: I have this configuration on all my pages, but now I moved one page to a different server and there's weird p tags in some shortcodes. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 9):

I solved this as best as possible by combining a slightly modified parse_shortcode_content function from Donal MacArthur (his originally manually calls wpautop... which I've removed. With the re-ordering of default filters to run wpautop much later... after the shortcode has already been processed instead of before.

```
// Clean up WordPress shortcode sormatting - important for nested shortcodes
// Adjusted from http://donalmacarthur.com/articles/cleaning-up-wordpress-shortcode-formatting/
function parse_shortcode_content( $content ) {

   /* Parse nested shortcodes and add formatting. */
    $content = trim( do_shortcode( shortcode_unautop( $content ) ) );

    /* Remove '' from the start of the string. */
    if ( substr( $content, 0, 4 ) == '' )
        $content = substr( $content, 4 );

    /* Remove '' from the end of the string. */
    if ( substr( $content, -3, 3 ) == '' )
        $content = substr( $content, 0, -3 );

    /* Remove any instances of ''. */
    $content = str_replace( array( '<p></p>' ), '', $content );
    $content = str_replace( array( '<p>  </p>' ), '', $content );

    return $content;
}
```

and moving the filters

```
// Move wpautop filter to AFTER shortcode is processed
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop', 99);
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100 );
```

**EDIT:**

The `parse_shortcode_content()` function is no longer required (if it ever was). Simply adjust the filter order.

Comment: with the filters re-ordered, i'm not even sure that i need to continue using the parse_shortcode_content( $content ) in lieu of simply do_shortcode($content) in my nested shortcodes

Comment: thanks but where are you calling parse_shortcode_content? if i put that code in functions.php nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: honestly, after a year, i can't really remember. i believe it was inside the shortcode function... in lieu of do_shortcode().  but try re-ordering the filters, that seemed to work for @dan

Comment: This code doesn't look right. How can a 4-character long or 3-character long string ever be `''` (an empty string)?

Comment: i have no idea.  it might not be right or even needed, anymore.

Answer (score 5):

In my case - this solution has broken one of the side shortcodes (revslider).

So I've found another solution here:
http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/shortcode-unautop-tp42085p42086.html

Which is to use another filter like this:

```
// Via http://www.wpexplorer.com/clean-up-wordpress-shortcode-formatting/
if ( !function_exists('wpex_fix_shortcodes') ) {
    function wpex_fix_shortcodes($content){
        $array = array (
            '<p>[' => '[',
            ']</p>' => ']',
            ']<br />' => ']'
        );
        $content = strtr($content, $array);
        return $content;
    }
    add_filter('the_content', 'wpex_fix_shortcodes');
}
```

It works fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here:

*[Remove wpautop from shortcode content / remove whitespace in buffering](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55782/remove-wpautop-from-shortcode-content-remove-whitespace-in-buffering/211784#answer-211784)*

It allows you to turn off wpautop for as many specific shortcodes as you want using this:

```
include "shortcode-wpautop-control.php";
chiedolabs_shortcode_wpautop_control(array('shortcodeone', 'shortcodetwo'));
```